# ASP.NET Empty value of Hidden Label field

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a hidden control on ASPX page which I set value In JQuery method. In the code behind, when I try to read the value it gives empty value for that hidden field. Here is the code:

.ASPX code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1"
            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Sign-in as <span id="Span1" class="caret"></span>
</button>
<asp:HiddenField ID="userrole" runat="server" />
```

JQuery code:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
    $("#dropdownMenu1").html($(this).text() + '<span class="caret"></span>');
    $('#<%= userrole.ClientID%>').val($(this).text());
});

$('#Sign_in_form').submit(function (e) {
    var selectedRole = $("#dropdownMenu1").text().trim();
    if (selectedRole == "Sign-in as" || selectedRole == null || selectedRole == "") {
        alert("Please select your Role!");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        alert("Signing in as: " + selectedRole);
    }
});
```

Code Behind:

```
if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string role = userrole.Value; //THIS GIVES EMPTY VALUE
    }
```

Comment: Have you verified that it actually contains a value before the postback? And how are you doing a postback btw?

Comment: @Andrei I have posted relevant code in JQuery section under my original post.

Comment: Thanks. But that does not answer the first question. Did you try debugging or console or anything to verify that the hidden field received any value?

Comment: Good observation!! I have debugged code and it appears that JQuery is throwing some error when setting hidden field value. Error is:
`SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=userrole.ClientID%>`

Comment: Is your jquery code in a separate file, or is it a part of asp.net page?

Comment: In a separate file... You are on right track, I just figured out the same reason for this problem. I put back Jquery code in ASPX page and it is working fine now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to my problem was that I was running JQuery method (which sets ASP Hidden label) in a separate Script file. I moved that method in ASPX page and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a session variable based on what you are asking.

```
//set the value on some action...
Session["provSel"] = {value};
...
if (IsPostBack)
{
    if (Session["provSel"] != null)
    {
        string role = Session["provSel"].ToString();
    }
}
```